# Which has Less impact on code execution: Read/Write of File or Shell Variables ?

Tags: shell, debugging

Code running on Linux that uses data from files to write to log files for debug purposes.  But this slows down code execution with file IO. Would read/write of OS environment (shell) variables be less intrusive/faster?

Comment: Writing to shell variables writes to memory (fast) rather than disk (relatively slow). However, I would be surprised if you notice the IO cost of writing a reasonably sized log file. If the log file is large, not sure how well that will work out writing log info to a shell variable (I don't know about maximum size of the variables, or how you intend to use the information).

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. Can you give examples of “logging with files” and “logging with environment variables” that we can compare?

Comment: To clarify:  Source code reads/writes from files and uses file contents to write data to external log file for run-time debugging.  Can shell variables edited at command line be read by code that is already running

Comment: To clarify:  Currently source code reads/writes integer from file and uses integer value deciding what data to write to external log file for run-time debugging.  Can file r/w be replaced by shell variables that command shell and executing code can read and write? Can shell variables edited at command line be read by code that is already running?